# XML Deserialization returns nothing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am deserializing this xml document

```
<root>
    <posts>
        <post>
            <id>7</id>
            <USERNAME>sohaib</USERNAME>
            <TITLE>help</TITLE>
            <USERID>1</USERID>
        </post>
        <post>
            <id>7</id>
            <USERNAME>sohaib</USERNAME>
            <TITLE>help</TITLE>
            <USERID>1</USERID>
        </post>    
    </posts>
    <comments>
        <comment>
            <COMMENTID>2</COMMENTID>
            <COMMENT_TEXT>help</COMMENT_TEXT>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <COMMENTID>2</COMMENTID>
            <COMMENT_TEXT>help</COMMENT_TEXT>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <COMMENTID>2</COMMENTID>
            <COMMENT_TEXT>help</COMMENT_TEXT>
        </comment>
    </comments>
</root>
```

and my C# code to deserialize this above xml file is

```
        XmlSerializer xsserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));            
        FileStream reader = new FileStream("abc.xml",FileMode.Open);
        object obj = xsserializer.Deserialize(reader);            
        root timeline = (root) obj;
```

Where my Root class looks like

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("root"), XmlType("root")]
public class root
{
    [XmlElement("Posts")]
    public List<Post>  Posts =new List<Post>();
    [XmlElement("Comments")]
    public List<Comment> Comments = new List<Comment>();

}
public class Post
{       
    [XmlElement("TITLE")]
    public string TITLE;
    [XmlElement("USERID")]
    public long USERID;        
    [XmlElement("USERNAME")]
    public string USERNAME;
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public long id;        
}

public class Comment
{        
    [XmlElement("COMMENTID")] public long COMMENTID;
    [XmlElement("COMMENT_TEXT")] public string COMMENT_TEXT;

}
```

I'm facing no exception no error but still it gives 0 items in posts and 0 in comments.
Can you please help me figure out where I'm going wrong. I appreciate your response.
Thanks Sohaib

Comment: Xml is case sensitive....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted, xml is case sensitive, hence you have to rename your classes in order to exactly match the names of the elements of the xml document.

Apart from that, you should change your `root` class to:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("root"), XmlType("root")]
public class root
{        
    [XmlArray("posts")]
    [XmlArrayItem("post")]
    public List<post> postList = new List<post>();
    [XmlArray("comments")]
    [XmlArrayItem("comment")]
    public List<comment> comments = new List<comment>();
}
```

`XmlArray` specifies the root node of the list contained within the root node of the document whereas `XmlArrayItem` specifies each element in that array.

You class definition would be ok if your xml document contained `<post>`, `<comment>` elements *directly* under `<root>`.

Comment: @Downvoter can you please explain the reason for your vote?

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlSerializer` is case sensitive.

If you fix your definitions, you should be good:

```
Posts -> posts (property name)
Comments -> comments (property name)
Post -> post (class name)
Comment -> comment (class name)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how can I fix definitions?

Comment: @sohaibjaved What did you get when you did the proposed changes in this answer?